# Response received from a url via php script is smaller than when I open it in browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to fetch this url via a script: http://api.alarabiya.net/sections/2/

But JSON response received is much smaller than when I open it directly in a browser,

please notice that I tried this url through CURL and set the same USER-AGENT of the browser and all request header used in the browser and I still get a smaller response.

Here's an exmaple using just file_get_contents

```
<?php 
    echo file_get_contents("http://api.alarabiya.net/sections/2/");
?>
```

My question is if there's a request size limit when using file_get_contents or if the PHP's memory can't handle it or what's the problem exactly?

When I CURLed this in shell it gave me the same o/p as in php (the trimmed output).

Comment: I could notice everytime I refresh the page the response is different but never got the full json string... is that correct?

Comment: yes that's what I'm getting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this:

```
$url = "http://api.alarabiya.net/sections/2/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
// This is what solved the issue (Accepting gzip encoding)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate");     
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Comment: How would you decode this? I used the json decode after doing this and I still get less results than what my url showed me. Example , the url showed me 9 result objects and after using the json decode function I only get 3? Am I missing somehting here? My latest question has the same setup your using including a decode after wards.